# Calculate TBN matrix in Geometry shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to calculate Tangent and bitangent in my geometry shader using dFdx and dFdy functions but I keep getting this error No matching overloaded function found: dFdx same for dFdy. Is there another way to calculate the tbn matrix without those functions?

Edit 1: I added some function of how I think I would need to calculate it because it seems I can't use the dFdx and dFdy in the geometry shader. I thought i would need to do it "manually"

```c
 #version 330 core
 layout(triangles) in ;
 layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out ;

 


 in vec3 fragPos[] ;
 in vec2 uv[] ;
 



 out vec3 tessNorm ;
 out vec2 uvGeo ;
 out vec3 gWorldPos_FS_in ;
 out mat3 gTBN ;

 vec3 px[3];
 vec3 py[3];
 vec2 uvx[3];
 vec2 uvy[3];
 vec3 T[3];
 vec3 B[3];
 mat3 TBN[3];

 void main()
 {

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
    { 
     gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position ;
     gWorldPos_FS_in = fragPos[i] ;
     uvGeo = uv[i];
     tessNorm = tessNormals[i];
        
     px[i] = vec3(dFdx(fragPos[i]), 0.0 , 0.0);
     py[i] = vec3(0.0, dFdy(fragPos[i]), 0.0);
     uvx[i] = vec2(dFdx(uv[i]), 0.0);
     uvy[i] = vec2(0.0, dFdy(uv[i]));
     T[i] = normalize(px[i] * uvy[i].y - py[i] * uvx[i].y);
     B[i] = normalize(-px[i] * uvy[i].x + py[i] * uvx[i].x);
     TBN[i] = mat3(T[i], B[i], tessNormals[i]);
     gTBN = TBN[i];
     EmitVertex() ;
    }
     EndPrimitive() ;

    }




vec3 getTangent()
{
   vec3 edge1 = vec3(gl_in[1].gl_Position) - vec3(gl_in[0].gl_Position);
   vec3 edge2 = vec3(gl_in[2].gl_Position) - vec3(gl_in[0].gl_Position);
   vec2 deltaUV1 = uv[1] - uv[0];
   vec2 deltaUV2 = uv[2] - uv[0];

   float f = 1.0 / (deltaUV1.x * deltaUV2.y - deltaUV2.x * deltaUV1.y);

   vec3 tangent;
   tangent.x = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.x - deltaUV1.y * edge2.x);
   tangent.y = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.y - deltaUV1.y * edge2.y);
   tangent.z = f * (deltaUV2.y * edge1.z - deltaUV1.y * edge2.z);

   return normalize(tangent);
}

vec3 getBitangent()
{
   vec3 edge1 = vec3(gl_in[1].gl_Position) - 
   vec3(gl_in[0].gl_Position);
   vec3 edge2 = vec3(gl_in[2].gl_Position) - vec3(gl_in[0].gl_Position);
   vec2 deltaUV1 = uv[1] - uv[0];
   vec2 deltaUV2 = uv[2] - uv[0];

   float f = 1.0 / (deltaUV1.x * deltaUV2.y - deltaUV2.x * deltaUV1.y);

   vec3 bitangent;
   bitangent.x = f * (-deltaUV2.x * edge1.x + deltaUV1.x * edge2.x);
   bitangent.y = f * (-deltaUV2.x * edge1.y + deltaUV1.x * edge2.y);
   bitangent.z = f * (-deltaUV2.x * edge1.z + deltaUV1.x * edge2.z);

   return normalize(bitangent);
}

mat3 getTBN()
{
     vec3 T = normalize(gTangents);
     vec3 N = normalize(gNormals);
     vec3 B = normalize(gBitangents);
     mat3 TBN = mat3(T, B, N);
     return TBN;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `dFdx` and `dFdy`?  The the partial derivatives are calculated based on fragments, so  `dFdx` and `dFdy` are only available in the fragment shader. You don't need these functions at all because you have the vertex coordinates and texture coordinates of all 3 vertices of a triangle.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I made some functions on how to calculate tangent and bitangent. Do you think they are correct?